# How to call method from services?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Logic of service: fetch data from api and set to properties. After that I call props on blazor client.
Service:

```
public class TmdbService
{
    private static JsonConfig _config = new JsonConfig();
    private readonly TMDbClient _client = new TMDbClient(_config.Settings.TApiKey);

    public async Task GetAllMovieInfo(string title, string lang = "ru")
    {
        SearchContainer<SearchMovie> results = await _client.SearchMovieAsync(title, lang);
        var movieData = results.Results.Take(1);
        foreach(var data in movieData)
        {
            new MovieDataDetail
            {
               Id = data.Id,
               Title = data.Title,
               OriginalTitle = data.OriginalTitle,
               ReleaseDate = data.ReleaseDate,
               Image = data.PosterPath,
               Popularity = data.Popularity,
               Overview = data.Overview
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
@page "/counter"
@using MovieApp.Shared.Services.TmdbApi
@using MovieApp.Shared.Models.MovieData

<div>
    <h1>The name of the movie: @detail.OriginalTitle</h1>
    <h1>The overview of the @title: @detail.Overview</h1>
    @*<h1>Ratings: @detail.IMDbRating</h1>*@
</div>

@code {
    TmdbService service;
    MovieDataDetail detail;
    string title = "lucy";

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        detail = new MovieDataDetail();
        service = new TmdbService();
        return service.GetAllMovieInfo(title);
    }
}
```

**My service works good while I use it in my console project.**

[A message from the error console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kspae.png)

I really haven't any ideas how to fix it. Help me, please

Comment: According to your stack trace, you have a problem in that your library `TMDbLib.RestClient` is setting the `Proxy` property to a value (even if it's null).  That [will throw the exception](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/75ae527a90c28effc47df1faf4dda48d86b8f980/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/BrowserHttpHandler/BrowserHttpHandler.cs#L78) you referenced.  The problematic line in the library is [this](https://github.com/LordMike/TMDbLib/blob/master/TMDbLib/Rest/RestClient.cs#L21).  Probably nothing you can do about it without relying on your library to update their code.

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks! I created the issue. By the way, I'm your new follower on github (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Are your services used on the server as well as on the client? If not, then define them on the client, and not on the Shared project...

You can't use your services the way you do... You should add your services to the DI container, as for instance:

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<ITmdbService, TmdbService>();
```

Note: The code above should be set in the Program.Main method of the Client project
Note: `ITmdbService` is an interface implemented by the `TmdbService` class. If you do not define such interface then your code should be:

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<TmdbService>();
```

Now, you should inject `ITmdbService` into your Counter component, like this

```
@page "/counter"
@inject ITmdbService TmdbService
```

Note that I'm using the interface identifier, not the class name. In case you did not define such interface you should do something like this:

```
@inject TmdbService TmdbService
```

The first TmdbService, from left to right, is the service class name. The second a property named TmdbService into which an instance of the object is inserted.

Now in your code you can use it like this:

```
TmdbService.GetAllMovieInfo(title);
```

Note that you'll have to add a using statement to the service if it is not defined on the client.